# Nodal analysis for nonlinear elements

Tags: current, calculation

I have this circuit. I'm trying to find the \$I_{3}, U_{3}, P_{3}\$. For the nonlinear element I have this volt-ampere characteristics: \$ I_{3} = 3U_{3}^2 -U_{3}\$.

[image]

That's what I am doing. Using the KCL \$ I_{1} = I_{2} + I_{3}\$. So \$1= I_{2}+I_{3}\$.

Using Ohm's law for \$ I_{2}\$  I have \$ 1 = 0,2U_{1}+I_{3}\$.

Usings KVL the equation is: \$ 0=I_{3}.R_{3}+U_{3} +U_{0}-U_{1}\$ and then \$ 0=3I_{3}+U_{3}-U_{1}\$.

I'm replacing \$ I_{3} \$ with \$ 3U_{3}^2 - U_{3}\$.

\$ 0 = 9U_{3}^2 - 3U_{3} +U_{3} -U_{1}\$;

then I get

\$U_{1} = 2U_{3}+9U_{3}^2\$

And I'm not sure what to do next. I saw an example with quadratic equation but i don't know to form the equation.

Comment: Please edit your schematic to clearly show where each voltage is measured and its polarity.

Comment: $$I_3 = 3U_3^2-U_3$$ is nonsensical. The left side is current and the right is voltage, so the units don't match. There has be some sort of impedance in this equation.

Comment: Here is my solution - https://ibb.co/y5mJTmH 
It's in bulgarian, the text says: using  KVL then KCL and quadratic equation.
The Ass. Prof. accepted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting R1 and I1 (which are in a Norton equivalent configuration) to a Thévenin equivalent, that way you will have a voltage supply followed by one linear resistor and one nonlinear resistor (after you calculate the series equivalent resistance of the linear resistors you have).

This should give you just two equations, one from KVL and one from the fact that all elements have the same current going through them. The resulting equation for current/voltage will be a polynomial of degree 2.

Answer (score 0):

In any case assuming your formulation is correct then:
Set -U1/9 == C
Set 2/9 == B
Then your equation becomes the familiar quadratic:
x^2 + Bx + C ==0

Which has two solutions:
x -> 1/2 (-B - Sqrt[B^2 - 4 C]) and

Substitute for B and C to get the solution, you may find one of these is meaningless for your particular case.
x -> 1/2 (-B + Sqrt[B^2 - 4 C])

Comment: The symbol \$ U \$ Is very commonly used to mean voltage, or often more specifically voltage-potential.